# GStreamer build windows cant import _giscanner

Tags: python-3.x, gstreamer

I'm trying to build GStreamer on windows using gst-build.
My environment:

- Visual studio 2019 Professional
- Python 3.9 64 bit
- Meson 0.58.999
- Ninja 1.10.2

the error message is:

```
>ninja -C build
ninja: Entering directory `build'
[1/30] Generating gir-glib with a custom command (wrapped by meson to set PATH)
FAILED: subprojects/gobject-introspection/gir/GLib-2.0.gir
[long list of python subprocess args with include patsh, c files etc]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Work\GStreamer-build\source\gst-build\build\subprojects\gobject-introspection\tools\g-ir-scanner", line 98, in <module>
    from giscanner.scannermain import scanner_main
  File "C:\Work\GStreamer-build\source\gst-build\build\subprojects\gobject-introspection\giscanner\scannermain.py", line 35, in <module>
    from giscanner.ast import Include, Namespace
  File "C:\Work\GStreamer-build\source\gst-build\build\subprojects\gobject-introspection\giscanner\ast.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .sourcescanner import CTYPE_TYPEDEF, CSYMBOL_TYPE_TYPEDEF
  File "C:\Work\GStreamer-build\source\gst-build\build\subprojects\gobject-introspection\giscanner\sourcescanner.py", line 35, in <module>
    from giscanner._giscanner import SourceScanner as CSourceScanner
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _giscanner: The specified module could not be found.

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

if I check the build directory:
[image]
So the file does build, but for some reason can't be imported.

I've seen from [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/cerbero/-/blob/1a8d2d35731eca4488ea2867948a7e3fa1884e8f/recipes/gobject-introspection/0001-Windows-Fix-building-and-running-on-Python-3.8.patch) that there were some changes to python 3.8 in how DLLs are searched for, but even if I manually open a python prompt in the parent directory and add both the parent and the giscanner directories to `sys.path` and using `os.add_dll_directory` I still can't import the module:

```
>>> import os,sys
>>> a = os.add_dll_directory(os.getcwd())
>>> a
<AddedDllDirectory('C:\\Work\\GStreamer-build\\source\\gst-build\\build\\subprojects\\gobject-introspection')>
>>> b = os.add_dll_directory(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'giscanner'))
>>> b
<AddedDllDirectory('C:\\Work\\GStreamer-build\\source\\gst-build\\build\\subprojects\\gobject-introspection\\giscanner')>
>>> sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
>>> sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'giscanner'))
```

further digging shows that pkg-config doesn't seem to know where to find gio, however that was also built sucessfully as part of the build so not sure why it doesn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure the actual problem, but the workaround is to revert Python to 3.7.9 (64 bit)

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-379

Its also been suggested you can build without that component using

-Dintrospection=disabled